# Proving a function is infinitely often continuously differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

$f(t)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j e^{-jt^2}$.
Prove that $f$ is infinitely often continuously differentiable for $t>0$, evaluate $f$ explicitly in the case where $a_j=1$ for all $j$.

So this function is continuous and bounded, thus by the M-test we can differentiate it term by term, which gives us the nth derivate as $\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j e^{-jt^2}2t$. Which to me, doesn't seem to be bounded? This question is asked in a weirstrass section, so I assume the proof must use that.

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{j = 0}^\infty a_j e^{-jt^2}$ or $\sum_{j = 0}^\infty a_j e^{-j}t^2$?

Comment: your first one, how it is posted. I did mean the nth derivative had 2t^n though.

Comment: There is a factor $-j$ missing in the terms of the derivative. And why is this not bounded?

Comment: You are correct I totally messed up that derivative. Well i see that the derivative is bounded, but if we are taking infinitely many derivatives, won't the -(2tj)^n term eventually become unbounded?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question. I interpreted it as prove we can differentiate it an infinite amount of times. Should I be trying to prove that it is continuously differentiable for an infinite amount of values?

Comment: The must be a condition on the size of the $a_j$. Otherwise the sequence may diverge (for instance if $a_j=e^{j^2}$.)